# Firebase undefined

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, undefined-variable

I'm trying to build a cloud messaging module working with firebase.

I have followed the magento dev docs tutorial on how to implement 3rd party javascript resources, I used requirejs.

And yet, when I try to initialize my app, the console returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`.

But the firebase sdk script tag IS present in the head tag of the page, and the link is valid and returns the sdk.
[image]

I tried to `console.log(firebase)` in the console after the page had fully loaded but it also returned undefined.

I tried the same thing on a basic html page and it did work this time. 
What could be the problem here ?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: I didn't, sorry. I plan on getting back to this in the future. Let's notify each other if we ever find a solution ^^

Comment: did you find the solution?. i want to integrate firebase with magento using js but getting the same error